# SVG Path Line Animation in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg

I have some path animations on a page and they work fine in all browsers except IE10/11. However I have some much more simpler animations doing the same thing on other pages, just with fewer of them, using pretty much the same code and they seem okay.

I think it may well be a performance bottleneck or so associated with IE.

If you view http://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/YXzbYY in IE10/11 you'll see there is quite a noticeable problem where the svgs appear glitchy or not fully rendered. Can't quite figure out what it is.

The relevant JS code from codepen:

```
    var cfg = {
            easing: [0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1],
            duration: 1200,
            delay: 500,
            layerDelay: 7000,
            width: 28,
            positioning: true,
            colors: [
                    '#027CA5',
                    '#75B5C6',
                    '#00FFD0',
                    '#00B994',
                    '#BEF5FE'
            ]
    }

    $('.shape-layer').each(function(i) {
            var $this = $(this);

            setTimeout(function() {
                    var $paths = $this.find('path');

                    strokeSetup($paths);
                    strokeOut($paths);

            }, cfg.layerDelay * i);
    });

    function strokeSetup($el) {
            $el.each(function(i) {
                    var $this = $(this),
                            pLen = Math.ceil($this.get(0).getTotalLength());

                    $this.css({
                            'stroke-dasharray': pLen,
                            'stroke-dashoffset': pLen,
                            'stroke-width': cfg.width
                    });
            });
    }

    function strokeOut($el) {
            var pathCount = $el.length,
                    iterationCount = pathCount;

            $el.each(function(i) {
                    var $this = $(this),
                            pLen = Math.ceil($this.get(0).getTotalLength()),
                            color = cfg.colors[getRandom(0, cfg.colors.length)];

                    setTimeout(function() {
                            $this.css({
                                    'stroke': color
                            });

                            if (cfg.positioning) {
                                    var side = ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'],
                                            cssO = {};

                                    $this.parent().css({
                                            top: 'auto',
                                            bottom: 'auto',
                                            left: 'auto',
                                            right: 'auto'
                                    });

                                    cssO[side[getRandom(0, 1)]] = getRandom(0, 40) + '%';

                                    var firstPos = cssO[Object.keys(cssO)[0]],
                                            sideAmount = (parseInt(firstPos) < 20) ? 100 : 20;

                                    cssO[side[getRandom(2, 3)]] = getRandom(0, sideAmount) + '%';

                                    $this.parent().css(cssO);
                            }

                            $this.velocity({
                                    'stroke-dashoffset': 0,
                            }, {
                                    duration: cfg.duration,
                                    easing: cfg.easing
                            });

                            if (!--iterationCount) {
                                    strokeIn($el);
                            }
                    }, cfg.delay * i);
            });

    }

    function strokeIn($el) {
            var pathCount = $el.length,
                    iterationCount = pathCount;

            $el.each(function(i) {
                    var $this = $(this),
                            pLen = Math.ceil($this.get(0).getTotalLength());

                    setTimeout(function() {

                            $this.velocity({
                                    'stroke-dashoffset': pLen
                            }, {
                                    duration: cfg.duration,
                                    easing: cfg.easing
                            });

                            if (!--iterationCount) {
                                    strokeOut($el);
                            }
                    }, cfg.delay * i);
            });
    }

    function getRandom(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
```

Comment: The way this is behaving on IE looks like redrawing errors to me.  It seems like IE is not calculating the redraw boxes correctly.  Perhaps it's related to your complicated arrangement of overlapping timeouts.  You could maybe work around the problem by making it so, on IE, only one dash-offset animation is running at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You may know this but **All** Internet Explorer versions do not support [SMIL](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil) Animating paths/ strokes etc is SMIL. Even via JavaScript. And jQuery is not fully compatible with the SVG DOM. Despite this manipulation being via CSS SVG properties, SVG "animations" via CSS are not ideal.

**SMIL** is dying & will be depreciated, which is why I recommend spending more time with libs like **Snap.svg** (ie9+) or **Raphaël** (ie6+), personally I would lean more towards Snap.

Anyway what about this animation you made?

In your circumstance from a wise professional standpoint this is not a scenario for progressive enhancement. Meaning you should compensate by turning that SVG animation into either a video, gif or static image and using it as a failback for IE browsers. e.g. via **modernizr** or whatever.

It is completely wrong that everything has to look the same in each browser. I believe a static jpg image is sufficient for those who lack features in this scenario.

Another thing I'm always aware of is that In regards to SVG Internet Explorer has "broke" compatibility up the chain of IE versions.

Comment: I use the same technique to animate similar path shapes on other pages of the site and they work fine. It's just this page with the more complex animations that doesn't work.

And I completely agree, if I don't find a solution I will fall back to an image, as it currently does if !Modernizr.svg or on mobile.

Comment: To be honest rarely use CSS for SVG animations I'm not entirely sure of the status of IE browsers and the use of CSS via SVG to animate, and how the versions differ. I appreciate there could be a more specific answer. BTW it looks great on my "Android Chrome" browser. ;)

Comment: @Undefined OP is not using SMIL animation here. This is just plain old manual CSS manipulation.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I realize. But to be honest, this practice of animating SVG with CSS should stop for a number of reasons.

This animation may alienating about 5-10% of users without a fix. IMHO it's not necessary but I'm sure others may disagree.

Edge will also not support the depreciating SMIL. We can use the new animation API today "Web Animations API" via the web animations polyfill. Either that or libs like Raphael, Snap & GSAP.

But jQuery is not a dedicated animation library for DOM/ Canvas/ SVG etc. It's just a general purpose lib.